# Find the term independent of $x$ in the expansion below

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Find the term independent of $x$ in the expansion of

$$\left(x - \frac 3 {x^2}\right)^{12}$$

Comment: the term independent to x will be when $x$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ have same power of $x$. and that will happen when $n=4$ i.e when $12C_4 (x)^8({\frac{1}{x^2}}^4)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You have to solve in natural numbers the linear system
\begin{cases}k-2\ell=0,\\k+\ell=12.\end{cases}